# Unable to strip brackets from string lists and convert them into an integer list

Tags: discord, discord.py, integer, strip

Today I was trying to expand my code a little by automating when the user goes online.

To do this, I use players.json from a FiveM server, the output looks like this:

```
{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":32,"identifiers":["license:948704b759518d74a682144ade779ac2a1e47c89","xbl:2535411592184061","live:914798949911430","discord:757436127689965649","fivem:3055601","license2:948704b759518d74a682144ade779ac2a1e47c89"],"name":"perez_04","ping":60},
```

and this goes on and on for every user.

I was able to retrieve all the information I needed, like the discord id and the player name, however, I have a problem.

What I have now is that every piece of data, including numbers-only, I store them as strings (I think this is the only way to get it to work with a list) like this:

```
            # ----- GET INFO -----
            users = {}
            for player_data_eu1 in online_eu1:
                player_name_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("name", "N/A")
                discord_id_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "discord" in identifier]
                in_game_id_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("id", "N/A")
                endpoint_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("endpoint", "N/A")
                license_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "license" in identifier]
                xbl_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "xbl" in identifier]
                live_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "live" in identifier]
                fivem_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "fivem" in identifier]
                license2_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "license2" in identifier]
                ping_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("ping", "N/A")

           #----- SAVE INFO -----
                users[str(player_name_eu1)] = player_name_eu1
                users[str(discord_id_eu1)] = discord_id_eu1
                users[str(in_game_id_eu1)] = in_game_id_eu1
                users[str(endpoint_eu1)] = endpoint_eu1
                users[str(license_eu1)] = license_eu1
                users[str(xbl_eu1)] = xbl_eu1
                users[str(live_eu1)] = live_eu1
                users[str(fivem_eu1)] = fivem_eu1
                users[str(license2_eu1)] = license2_eu1
                users[str(ping_eu1)] = ping_eu1
```

and everything works fine however I need the discord ID as an integer and out of the squared brackets because the output of the print message:

```
                print("Loaded online data for:", player_name_eu1)
                print("Player Name:", player_name_eu1)
                print("Discord ID:", discord_id_eu1_i)
                print("In-Game ID:", in_game_id_eu1)
                print("\n")  # Add a newline after each user's data
```

gives me the discord id as for example:

```
Discord ID: ['633993765494033'] # Note that this is not an actual discord ID, its just to show.
```

I need to remove the `' '` and the `[ ]` from the final product, but I'm unable to do so.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
                if discord_id_eu1:
                    discord_id_eu1_i = [int(s.strip("[]'")) for s in discord_id_eu1]

                elif not discord_id_eu1:
                    print("No discord ID, skipping")
                    continue
                    
                else:
                    discord_id_eu1 = []
                    discord_id_eu1_i = []
```

but this only stripped the `' '`, and not the `[ ]`. I tried everything!

Please not that discord_id_eu1 is a STRING list full of MULTIPLE STRINGS of Numbers, so converting it into an integer without separating each number first throws an error

> An unexpected error occurred: argument of type 'int' is not iterable

Here is the full code section, for any questions, please feel free to ask. Thank you in advance!

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=20)
async def check_activities():
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:
            if member.bot:
                continue

            # Check if member has Trainee, Cadet, or SWAT role
            allowed_role_ids = [1033432392758722682, 962226985222959145, 958274314036195359]
            has_allowed_role = any(role.id in allowed_role_ids for role in member.roles)
            
            if not has_allowed_role:
                continue  # Skip members without the specified roles
              
            try:
              # ---- EU1 ----
                request_online_eu1 = requests.get(api_url_online_eu1)
                request_online_eu1.raise_for_status()  # Raise an HTTPError for bad responses
                online_eu1 = request_online_eu1.json()
                time.sleep(1)
        
                if request_online_eu1.status_code == 200:
                    print("Status Code: 200 (OK)")
                    online_eu1 = request_online_eu1.json()
                    
                else:
                    print("Status code not 200, locked program")
                    
                users = {}
                for player_data_eu1 in online_eu1:
                    player_name_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("name", "N/A")
                    discord_id_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "discord" in identifier]
                    in_game_id_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("id", "N/A")
                    endpoint_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("endpoint", "N/A")
                    license_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "license" in identifier]
                    xbl_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "xbl" in identifier]
                    live_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "live" in identifier]
                    fivem_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "fivem" in identifier]
                    license2_eu1 = [identifier.split(":")[1] for identifier in player_data_eu1.get("identifiers", []) if "license2" in identifier]
                    ping_eu1 = player_data_eu1.get("ping", "N/A")
                    
                    users[str(player_name_eu1)] = player_name_eu1
                    users[str(discord_id_eu1)] = discord_id_eu1
                    users[str(in_game_id_eu1)] = in_game_id_eu1
                    users[str(endpoint_eu1)] = endpoint_eu1
                    users[str(license_eu1)] = license_eu1
                    users[str(xbl_eu1)] = xbl_eu1
                    users[str(live_eu1)] = live_eu1
                    users[str(fivem_eu1)] = fivem_eu1
                    users[str(license2_eu1)] = license2_eu1
                    users[str(ping_eu1)] = ping_eu1
                   
                    
                    if discord_id_eu1:
                        discord_id_eu1_i = [int(s.strip("[]'")) for s in discord_id_eu1]

                        
                    elif not discord_id_eu1:
                        print("No discord ID, skipping")
                        continue
                        
                    else:
                        discord_id_eu1 = []
                        discord_id_eu1_i = []
                        

                    
                    print("Loaded online data for:", player_name_eu1)
                    print("Player Name:", player_name_eu1)
                    print("Discord ID:", discord_id_eu1_i)
                    print("In-Game ID:", in_game_id_eu1)
                    print("\n")  # Add a newline after each user's data
              
              # ------ LOGIC ------
              # ---- EU1 ----
                    if member.id in discord_id_eu1_i:
                        print(f"Success!, ID: {in_game_id_eu1}, NAME: {player_name_eu1}, DISCORD: {discord_id_eu1_i}")
   
             # ---- EXCEPTIONS ----
            except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as e:
                print(f'HTTPError: {e}')
            except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:
                print(f'ConnectionError: {e}')
            except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
                print(f'RequestException: {e}')
            except Exception as e:
                print(f'An unexpected error occurred: {e}')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you get from the server is in JSON Format. Treat it as such. Right now you are working with strings, which complicates everything.

Try this instead:

```
import json

# The provided JSON string
json_string = '{"endpoint":"127.0.0.1","id":32,"identifiers":["license:948704b759518d74a682144ade779ac2a1e47c89","xbl:2535411592184061","live:914798949911430","discord:757436127689965649","fivem:3055601","license2:948704b759518d74a682144ade779ac2a1e47c89"],"name":"perez_04","ping":60}'

# Deserialize the JSON string into a Python dictionary
data = json.loads(json_string)

# Access the data
print("Endpoint:", data["endpoint"])
print("ID:", data["id"])
print("Identifiers:", data["identifiers"])
print("Name:", data["name"])
print("Ping:", data["ping"])
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the "discord_id_eu1_i" variable? If it is a list you can just use "discord_id_eu1_i[0]" to access the first list element, which is the ID that you want.

If it is a string you could just filter for Numbers in your string. For example by using

```
filtered_ID = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, discord_id_eu1_i))
```

keep in mind that its still a string afterwards. If you want to use it in discord.py context you need to convert it into an integer. For example by:

```
int(filtered_ID)
```